# Can my reducer use a Set as an initial value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

I'm attempting to reduce an array of objects to a Set of unique values.  To do so, I'm trying to use a Set as the accumulator to a `reduce()` operation.

```
subscriptions = [
    {list_id: 'abc', name: 'nom', subscribed: true},
    {list_id: 'abc', name: 'nom', subscribed: true},
    {list_id: 'ghi', name: 'nom', subscribed: false}];

return subscriptions.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    if (currentValue.subscribed) {
      return accumulator.add(currentValue.list_id);
    }
  }, new Set());
```

My tests are reporting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Is what I'm attempting to do possible?  Do I need to do this some other way?

Comment: you need to return accumulator in case of if condition fails too

Comment: @CodeManiac Is right. If `currentValue.subscribed` is `false`, then you return *nothing*. Therefore in the next iteration, `accumulator` is `undefined`, and you try to call `add` on it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll mark the question as answered when it lets me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return `accumulator` in case your if condition fails. otherwise by default it return `undefined` ( implicitly ).

```js
let subscriptions = [
    {list_id: 'abc', name: 'nom', subscribed: true},
    {list_id: 'abc', name: 'nom', subscribed: true},
    {list_id: 'ghi', name: 'nom', subscribed: false}];

let  op = subscriptions.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    if (currentValue.subscribed) {
      accumulator.add(currentValue.list_id);
    }
    return accumulator
  }, new Set());
  
  console.log([...op])
```

Comment: Or `if (currentValue.subscribed) { accumulator.add(currentValue.list_id); } return accumulator;`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reducing the array, you could filter first and map `list_id` and take the constructor of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
var subscriptions = [{ list_id: 'abc', name: 'nom', subscribed: true }, { list_id: 'abc', name: 'nom', subscribed: true }, { list_id: 'ghi', name: 'nom', subscribed: false }],
    uniqueIds = new Set(subscriptions
        .filter(({ subscribed }) => subscribed)
        .map(({ list_id }) => list_id)
    );

console.log([...uniqueIds]);
```

Comment: Concurring with what Tyler pointed out.... I need to include the knowledge about 'subscribed'

Comment: The updated answer has a `filter` then `map` operation (two passes on the data) contrasted with one pass using the `reduce` operation.  Wouldn't the single 'reduce' operation be preferred?

Comment: meanwhile using `filter` before works too, in this way you are doing two loops rather than one using a `reduce`. In this case doesn't matter, but it's worth to say anyway

Comment: for three or 1000 data sets, it does not matter.